# Flutter released apk package conflicts error while installing?

Tags: android, flutter, package, google-play, apk

I am learning flutter development. I have created signed apk and .abb with credentials like keystore.jks. Also published the .abb to the playstore.

I have also installed the app from Google Play store. Now I have created new version and made the new released APK with same credentials. Before updating the new version to play store as a developer I am testing the signed apk but facing the issues like:

"App not installed package conflicts with existing package"

Instead of this error it should be updated. What you think any other issue?

Comment: What happens when you uninstall the existing app from the Store before installing your app locally?

Comment: Have you increased version name and version code ? Seems that the new version is not considered as an update

Comment: @TamHuynh It works when I uninstall the existing play store app and then installing the new released apk, but after publishing new new version then all the user will face the same issue?

Comment: @Bruno I have increased both in pubspec.yml file by one then it should be update while installing.

Comment: change the name of the package from Local to release. You have deployed the app from the system and now trying to install it from play store causes these issue

Comment: Of course not, users only get the build from the Store, not from your development machine. When you upload a new build to the Play Store, it re-signs the APK with a different keystore and does other stuff. So 2 builds will conflict when installed on the same device. Only you as a developer will face this.

Comment: It may be, I have already the play store app in the device and want to deploy it from my system.

Comment: @TamHuynh But I am generating signed APK with same credentials like for release mode not for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion, I think this can explain the problem you are encountering:

- The build from your machine is signed with your keystore => that's normal
- The build you upload to Play Store, then install on the device is **Signed again** by Play App Signing ([reference link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll)).

They are conflict because although they have the same package name and the same release build, they are signed by different keys.

And don't worry, only you as a developer encounter this problem, users always get the final app from Play Store which is signed by Play app Signing, so there will be no conflict from the user side.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Let me apply these ones then let you.

Comment: Besides testing the release build from your machine, you can open a Closed Beta Testing track on Play Store console and enroll yourself in the tester team. This way you can test your release build after being signed by Play App Signing before promoting it to the final Release track. Always double check on Closed Beta before pushing it to release. And install new version on Store will never conflict to the current app which is also from Store

Comment: Hi @RakeshSaini how is your check? If this can help then just confirm my support

Comment: Your clarification is helpful, once the new version will update then sure I will mark to check it.

Comment: @RakeshSaini did it work? My users are also facing this issue.

Comment: Yes its correct, you can not update the APK from different SHA fingerprints.